# Unit Testing a Firefox Addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, mozmill

In working on a firefox addon, i've found the task of unit testing to be kinda janky and difficult to setup. Anyone have recommendations on how to setup unit tests for an addon? Any tools or additional addons found to be helpful?

I've found Mozmill [ https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9018 ], which I think will be useful to an extent, but it's more of a high level tool and i'm looking for a tool or approach that works for more low level testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about UxU ( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6357 ) ?

Comment: that looks exactly like what i'm looking for! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I used code-level unit testing with **Mozmill**. I "hooked" *resource://* path of **Mozmill** by programmatically adding testing add-on ([Urim](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/200751/)) path to it in test initialization (setupModule function). As the result i can test any peace of code of my testing add-on like it is own code of **Mozmill**. Look [here](https://code.google.com/p/urim/source/checkout) for an example. As i understand, this is you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The new JetPack Add-On SDK they are working on for Firefox 4.0 has testing built in. It isn't documented yet though, but it's something to watch. It looks like you run "cfx test" which will run the tests.

Some links:
JetPack - https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/
Add-On SDK Documentation - https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/1.0b2/docs/
Add-On SDK Test Harness - https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/api/test-harness

Answer (score 1):

Also see http://paulgu.com/wiki/Unit_Testing_Framework. I haven't used it, but it seems like a simpler and lighter-weight approach that might be easier to integrate. I think it could be better packaged to make it easier to add to an existing extension, but that is probably a straightforward refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver or Selenium?

Comment: Doesn't really satisfy the unit testing need. The tools mentioned and the one I mention in my question are at a higher level than what i'm looking for. I'm looking for approaches people use for code-level unit testing.